# Drawing D3 Diagonals using ScalaJS

Tags: scala, d3.js, scala.js

I'm having troubles trying to draw "Diagonal" lines using the ScalaJS D3 library here: https://github.com/spaced/scala-js-d3

I started with the original JS example here: http://jsfiddle.net/MetalMonkey/JnNwu/

```
// root is a js.Dynamic holding JSON data
val nodes = 
  tree
  .nodes(root)
  .reverse

val svg = d3.select("#tree").append("svg")
val links = tree.links(nodes)
val projector = (d: Node, num: Double) => { js.Tuple2(d.x, d.y) }
val diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(projector)

val link = 
  svg
  .data(links)
  .append("line")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .style("stroke-width", 5)
  .attr("d", diagonal)
```

Attempting to pass the "diagonal" function gets me:

```
[error]  found   : (scala.scalajs.js.Dynamic, Int, scala.scalajs.js.UndefOr[Int]) => String
[error]  required: scala.scalajs.js.Function3[org.singlespaced.d3js.Link[scala.scalajs.js.Dynamic],Int,scala.scalajs.js.UndefOr[Int],scala.scalajs.js.|[scala.scalajs.js.|[Double,String],Boolean]]
[error]              .attr("d", (value: Dynamic, x: Int,y:  js.UndefOr[Int]) =>   "Completely lost.")
[error]                                                                      ^
[error] one error found
```

At a loss, I tried to just pass *any* function that fit the required signature:

```
val link = 
  svg
  .data(tree.links(nodes))
  .append("line")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .style("stroke-width", 5)
  .attr("d", (value: Link[Dynamic], x: Int,y:  js.UndefOr[Int]) =>  "Totally lost": Primitive)
```

Which compiles, only to result in this error being thrown in the browser:

```
uncaught exception: scala.scalajs.runtime.UndefinedBehaviorError: An undefined
behavior was detected: [object Object] is not an instance of org.singlespaced.d3js.Link
```

I don't really recognized the

```
scala.scalajs.js.|[scala.scalajs.js.|[Double,String],Boolean]
```

type, and I haven't found any results explaining if it's a ScalaJS disjunction/either/etc or if that's even relevant. I'm new to ScalaJS and D3, so any pointers are helpful.

Comment: line elements don't have a d attribute. d is for a path.

Comment: Does that mean I'm wrong in appending "line" instead of "path", or wrong for trying to set the "d" attribute rather than $otherAttr ?

Comment: You could go either way, but you do need to pick one or the other.